# How to use docker-abuild in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I want to use [docker-abuild](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/docker-abuild) to build imagemagick in a Dockerfile. I use the following in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpinelinux/docker-abuild as imagickbuilder
COPY imagick/APKBUILD.imagick /home/builder/package/APKBUILD
COPY imagick/APKBUILD.imagick /home/builder/APKBUILD
COPY imagick/disable-avaraging-tests.patch /home/builder/package/disable-avaraging-tests.patch
COPY imagick/webmaster@mycompany.com-5b42f8ed.rsa /home/builder/ssh.rsa
COPY imagick/webmaster@mycompany.com-5b42f8ed.rsa.pub /etc/apk/keys/ssh.rsa.pub
ARG DABUILD_ARCH=aarch64
RUN dabuild -r
# tried abuild -r as well as builder -r
```

Regardless of what APKBUILD file I have/use, I'm getting the following error while building with `docker build -t test .`:

```
#...
#11 [7/7] RUN dabuild -r
#11 sha256:8c6e0fa4c055b4f5bbb7f633a3b4b4009cda31017a26dc48a047fd02466ce60c
#11 0.658 /bin/sh: dabuild: not found
#11 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dabuild -r]: exit code: 127
------
 > [7/7] RUN dabuild -r:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dabuild -r]: exit code: 127
```

I'm getting the same error with `abuild -r` and `abuilder -r`. Any ideas?

JFYI, I'm running this under macOS Monterey 12.2.1 with an M1 Pro MacBook Pro.